# ajax to https/ssl when posting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ssl

So I have a payment page that is setup that uses ajax to post data to a process script that is tied to Authorize.net. When not using the SSL on the page, the ajax seems to work just fine and then the success divide rolls up like it should. But when I attempt to post the data under  an SSL, the page just posts the data, and the page switches showing only the divide on the new page.

So my question is, is there a way that I can allow ajax to post through the SSL and still get the same ajax/jquery results that I do on a normal page? Any reference on how to do so would be great.

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't add much security.  You need to serve the **entire page**, including all scripts & resources, under SSL, from start to finish.  Otherwise, an attacker can modify your JS to steal credit card numbers directly.

Comment: the entire page is in fact being served under the SSL when the payment page loads. And where the information posts to is also calling the SSL as well. But it loses the slide up functionality that normally happens which is done with jquery and ajax.

Comment: Do you get any script errors in the console?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I actually loaded up the console and then found out that the jquery from google wasn't loaded with an SSL. Once I changed that - it works as expected. Thanks for the help!